# How to remove quantity from WooCommerce mini card

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

how to remove or hide **quantity** in **woocommerce mini card** ?
[woocommerce minicard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zaYiP.png)

I use this code but it just removes quantity field in **product page**.

```
function wc_remove_all_quantity_fields( $return, $product ) {return true;}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_is_sold_individually', 'wc_remove_all_quantity_fields', 10, 2 );
```

Answer (score 0):

There are few ways to remove the qty from the mini cart.

**With filter**

```
function remove_cart_item_quantity($product_quantity, $cart_item_key, $cart_item)
{
    return '';
}
add_filter('woocommerce_widget_cart_item_quantity', 'remove_cart_item_quantity', 10, 3);
```

**Editing the template**
https://woocommerce.com/document/woocommerce-theme-developer-handbook/
https://woocommerce.com/document/template-structure/
In your theme you have to add `add_theme_support('woocommerce');` if you dont have it already. After that you have to create folder woocommerce in your active theme. Inside create another folder cart and inside create file `mini-cart.php`

Copy the content of the original `mini-cart.php` and modify to your needs.
https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/trunk/plugins/woocommerce/templates/cart/mini-cart.php

**This method should be used for more advanced modifications than removing a filter since it will require maintance for future updates if WooCommerce do some changes on that template.**